# How to get unique value in jQuery?

Tags: select, jquery

I am learning jQuery.

I have the following chunk of code in an HTML file:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align='center'>
        <div>
            <a id='get_this' href='#'>
            <input type='hidden' id='id' value='1'><img src='images/1.gif'></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align='center'>
        <div>
            <a id='get_this' href='#'>
            <input type='hidden' id='id' value='2'><img src='images/2.gif'></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align='center'>
        <div>
            <a id='get_this' href='#'>
            <input type='hidden' id='id' value='3'><img src='images/3.gif'></a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is, when I click any of the image, I can get the <input hidden> value, so that I can display the information. For example, I click the id=1, then I will display information on id1 in somewhere else. I tried this:

```
$("a#get_this").click(function(){
        var id = $('input[type=hidden]#id').val();
        window.alert("You have chosen the id: " + id);
});
```

It always return id: 1 to me.

Comment: This kind of problem occurs over and over again ;)

Comment: @Felix King: You mean, you had this problem before? I am new to jquery =(

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery. The problem is that you assign the same ID to multiple elements. This is just an HTML problem. I meant that a lot questions are posted, where assigning the same ID is the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs have to be unique in a HTML document. I think the behaviour is undefined if you have more than one element with the same ID, but most browser probably pick the first one then.

Use classes instead:

```
<table width="100%"> 
<tr> 
    <td align='center'> 
        <div> 
            <a class='get_this' href='#'> 
            <input type='hidden' value='1'><img src='images/1.gif'></a> 
        </div> 
    </td> 
    <td align='center'> 
        <div> 
            <a class='get_this' href='#'> 
            <input type='hidden' value='2'><img src='images/2.gif'></a> 
        </div> 
    </td> 
    <td align='center'> 
        <div> 
            <a class='get_this' href='#'> 
            <input type='hidden' value='3'><img src='images/3.gif'></a> 
        </div> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

and JS:

```
$("a.get_this").click(function(){
        // find all input elements inside "a" (which is only one)
        var id = $(this).find('input').val(); 
        window.alert("You have chosen the id: " + id);
    });
```

Comment: Amazing, you save my life (today). I have been try and debug it for few hours. @_@ And my problem is solved soon after I posted this question here. Thanks guys (for all the answerers) =)

Answer (score 1):

You use the same ID multiple times when an ID should be unique. You should be using classes instead:

```
<a class='get_this' href='#'>
```

and then

```
$("a.get_this").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

id should be unique in a document. Change the id `get_this` to a class instead:

```
<a class="get_this" href="#">..</a>
```

You can then get the value of the input field as:

```
$("a.get_this").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).children("input:hidden").val();
    window.alert("You have chosen the value: " + id);
});
```

The hidden input tag can simply be:

```
<input type='hidden' value='1'>
```

---

Note that some browsers may return more than 1 results back when you do:

```
$("a#get_this").length
```

but that behavior is not guaranteed, and you should never rely on it. It's better to use classes or something else for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Ids have to be unique, so you can't have multiple elements with the same id.** But if you want this you could attach the click handler to the image, add the id of the 'data' you want to your image too (let's say `<img id="data1" ... />`). Now you have it.

Remark: ids can't start with a number. They have to start with a letter.